# Laravel pass view field input data to controller and then return calculated value in disabled field

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller

So what i want to do is take values from user input, then do some calculation with it inside the controller with method and that method return value to be displayed in field below with disabled attribute that will on form submit be passed to database. So what i have in view is:

```
            <input class="form-control {{ $errors->has('price') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" type="number" name="price" id="price" value="{{ old('price', '') }}" step="0.001" required>
            <input class="form-control {{ $errors->has('quantity') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="{{ old('quantity', '') }}" step="0.001" required>
            <input class="form-control {{ $errors->has('other_expenses') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" type="number" name="other_expenses" id="other_expenses" value="{{ old('other_expenses', '') }}" step="0.01" required>
            <input class="form-control {{ $errors->has('coefficient') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" type="number" name="coefficient" id="coefficient" value="{{ old('coefficient', '') }}" step="0.001" required>
            <input class="form-control {{ $errors->has('total') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" type="number" name="total" id="total" value="{{ old('total', '') }}" step="0.001" disabled>
```

And then i want to do some calculation through controller and return some value in "total" field.
So in my controller i should accept that tada and then calculate something like:
total = (price*quantity*other_expenses)*coefficient

Comment: you can make an ajax call to get calculated value.

Comment: can u elaborate more how should i do that , cuz i didnt end up with working solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code above, it looks like everything you need for the calculation is there on the form. Is there a particular action that happens on the controller?

For example, if all you need you intend to calculate is `total = (price * quantity * other_expenses ) * coefficient`, you may not necessarily need to send the data to the controller.

You can use Alpine js to perform the calculation right on the page.

Follow the step below:

1. Include alpine in your layout 
   `<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>`
2. 

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
<div x-data="{
              price: parseInt( '120'), 
              quantity: parseInt( '5'), 
              other_expenses: parseInt( '50'),
              coefficient: parseInt( '2') 
            }">
    <input type="number" name="price" x-model.number="price"  />
    <input type="number" name="quantity" x-model.number="quantity" />
    <input type="number" name="other_expenses" x-model.number="other_expenses" />
    <input type="number" name="coefficient" x-model.number="coefficient" />
    <input type="text" x-bind:value="price * quantity * other_expenses * coefficient" name="total" disabled />
</div>
```

Note: You can pass the old values like so `price: parseInt( '{{ old('price') }}')`

You can submit and the total should be submitted.

If you must use the controller for the calculations, you may have to use ajax with vuejs or jquery.

UPDATE: For the ajax implementation, you can use alpine 'fetch' to make API call to the backend for any validation.

```php
<div x-data="{
    price: parseInt( '120'), 
    quantity: parseInt( '5'), 
    other_expenses: parseInt( '50'),
    coefficient: parseInt( '2') ,
    data: null,
    calculateTotal() {
            fetch('/calculateTotal/route/url',{
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    price: this.price,
                    quantity: this.quantity,
                    other_expenses:this.other_expenses,
                    coefficient:this.coefficient
                }),
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                    this.data = data
                    console.log(data)

            })
            .catch(error => {
                    console.log({ error })
                });
    }">
<input type="number" name="price" x-model.number="price"  @keyup.debounce.750ms="calculateTotal()"  />
<input type="number" name="quantity" x-model.number="quantity" @keyup.debounce.750ms="calculateTotal()" />
<input type="number" name="other_expenses" x-model.number="other_expenses" @keyup.debounce.750ms="calculateTotal()" />
<input type="number" name="coefficient" x-model.number="coefficient" @keyup.debounce.750ms="calculateTotal()" />

<input type="text" x-bind:value="data.total" name="total" readonly />

//Your web.php or api.php depending on where the 
Route::post('gettotal', 'ProductController@getTotal');

//Controller
public function getTotal(Request $request)
{
    $data = [
        'total' => $request->price * $request->quantity * $request->other_expenses * $request->coefficient; //You can include any validation here
    ];
    return response()->json($data)
}
```

Comment: Yeah i wanted it to be server side calculated as i dont like data manipulation... With this there is no server side validation, and also if i set field to disabled it will show price but store method doesnt store value in database... How can i validate this value using back end?

**
Figured value passing out with readonly, now i just need to validate value...

Comment: @CicovicDejan Apologies for my delayed response. I have included the backend api response. If you can include the specific validations.

Comment: yeah i have done it 2 days from then in pure javascript, and even deleted previous alpine js data and replaced with javascript. I mean on same example but with api route... same principle but not in alpine. Thank you so much anyway.